# Calculate Duration and Average of CSV file data using python

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I have a csv file and what I want to do is create a script where user inputs the source ip and destination ip. Once that matches in the csv file. It will take all the source and destination ip the user entered and calculate the time difference between the sessions of multiple matches of user input of a source and destination IP's. Lastly, the script will do the average of the duration as well. Below is an example of my csv column A data however the csv has several column like Time, Source Ip, and Destination IP.Instead of using three different column we can just use Column A that has three info  we need already.

_raw

2013-07-18 04:54:15.871 UDP    172.12.332.11:20547   172.12.332.11:20547 
->    172.56.213.80:53  CREATE  Ignore        0

2013-07-18 04:54:15.841 UDP      192.33.230.81:37192   192.81.130.82:37192 
->    172.81.123.70:53    CREATE  Ignore        0

2013-07-18 04:54:15.831 TCP      172.12.332.11:42547   172.12.332.11:42547
->  172.56.213.80:53 CREATE  Ignore        0

Below is my code in python that does not work anymore. All that happens now is it skips the ip's and does nothing. Please help me fix as I am lost to why it does not work.

My code in python:

```
import sys
from sys import argv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

script, source, destination, filename = argv #assign the script arguments to variables
line_num = 0 #for keeping track of the current line number
count = 0 #for counting occurrences of source/destination IPs
occurrences = [] 
#array to store all of the matching occurrences of source/destination IPs

line_array = [] #array to store line numbers
avg = 0 #average
total = 0 #sum of microseconds

#function for converting timedelta to microseconds
def timedelta_to_microtime(td):
return td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 86400) * 1000000
#use 'try' to catch IOexception
try:
for line in open(filename):
        #if the first character is a number, read line

            if line[0].isdigit():
           if source and destination in line:
            #increment counter for each occurrence of matching  IP combination
            count+=1
            #get the first 23 characters from the line (the date/time)
             #and convert it to a datetime object using the "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
             #format, then add it to the array named "occurrences."
        occurrences.append(datetime.strptime(line[:23], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
            line_array.append(line_num)
        #if the first character is not a number, it's the headers, skip them
        else:
            line_num += 2
            continue #go to next line
        line_num += 1 #counter to keep track of line (solely for testing purposes)
#if the script can't find the data file, notify user and terminate

except IOError:
    print "\n[ERROR]: Cannot read data file, check file name and try again."
    sys.exit()

print "\nFound %s matches for [source: %s] and [destination: %s]:\n" % (len(occurrences), source, destination)

if len(occurrences) != 0: 
#if there are no occurrences, there aren't any times to show! so don't print this line
    print "Time between adjacent connections:\n"

for i in range(len(occurrences)):
if i == 0:
        continue #if it is the first slot in the array, continue to next              slot (can't  subtract from array[0-1] slot)
else:
    #find difference in timedate objects (returns difference in timedelta object)
       difference = (occurrences[i-1]-occurrences[i])
       #for displaying line numbers
       time1 = line_array[i-1]
       time2 = line_array[i]
       #convert timedelta object to microseconds for computing average
       time_m = timedelta_to_microtime(difference)
       #add current microseconds to existing microseconds
       total += time_m
       print "Line %s and Line %s: %s" % (time1, time2, difference)

#check to make sure there are things to take the average of
if len(occurrences) != 0:
    #compute average
    #line read as: total divided by the length of the occurrences array as a float
    #minus 1, divided by 1,000,000 (to convert microseconds back into seconds)
    avg = (total / float((len(occurrences)-1)))/1000000
    print "\nAverage: %s seconds" % (avg)
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit better what you want to do? 1. User enters source and destination IP. 2. You search the csv file for every line where the source and the destination match the users input 3. you add all the timestamps (?)

Comment: So: 1. User enters source and destination IP. 2. You search the csv file for every line where the source and the destination match the users input. 3. Calculate the difference between `i`th row and `i+1`th row 4. calculate the mean of those differences.

Comment: 1 and 2 are correct. for 3. The timestamps is already there. Every row in a single column has the time stamp, source and destination ips. What I would like the script to do is. Take user input and match against ever row that matches the ips with same source and destination. Then I would like it to calculate the time interval between the flows. So lets say 10 ips match the user input. Take their time and calculate the time difference of two flows. Giving us an output of five time intervals and an average for all the 5 sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem much easier if you use a high level library like pandas. Let me demonstrate:

Let's say you have a next data file saved in `file.csv`:

```
2013-07-18 04:54:15.871 UDP 172.12.332.11:20547 172.12.332.11:20547 -> 172.56.213.80:53 CREATE Ignore 0
2013-07-18 04:54:15.841 UDP 192.33.230.81:37192 192.81.130.82:37192 -> 172.81.123.70:53 CREATE Ignore 0
2013-07-18 04:54:15.831 TCP 172.12.332.11:42547 172.12.332.11:42547 -> 172.56.213.80:53 CREATE Ignore 0
2013-07-18 04:54:15.821 UDP 192.33.230.81:37192 192.81.130.82:37192 -> 172.81.123.70:53 CREATE Ignore 0
2013-07-18 04:54:15.811 TCP 172.12.332.11:42547 172.12.332.11:42547 -> 172.56.213.80:53 CREATE Ignore 0
```

First we read it into a data frame:

```
>>> df = pd.read_table('file.csv', sep=' ', header=None, parse_dates=[[0,1]])
>>> print df.to_string()
                         0_1    2                    3                    4   5                 6       7       8  9
0 2013-07-18 04:54:15.871000  UDP  172.12.332.11:20547  172.12.332.11:20547  ->  172.56.213.80:53  CREATE  Ignore  0
1 2013-07-18 04:54:15.841000  UDP  192.33.230.81:37192  192.81.130.82:37192  ->  172.81.123.70:53  CREATE  Ignore  0
2 2013-07-18 04:54:15.831000  TCP  172.12.332.11:42547  172.12.332.11:42547  ->  172.56.213.80:53  CREATE  Ignore  0
3 2013-07-18 04:54:15.821000  UDP  192.33.230.81:37192  192.81.130.82:37192  ->  172.81.123.70:53  CREATE  Ignore  0
4 2013-07-18 04:54:15.811000  TCP  172.12.332.11:42547  172.12.332.11:42547  ->  172.56.213.80:53  CREATE  Ignore  0
```

We need only the 0_1, 4th and 6th column

```
>> df = df[['0_1', 4, 6]]
>> print df.to_string()
                         0_1                    4                 6
0 2013-07-18 04:54:15.871000  172.12.332.11:20547  172.56.213.80:53
1 2013-07-18 04:54:15.841000  192.81.130.82:37192  172.81.123.70:53
2 2013-07-18 04:54:15.831000  172.12.332.11:42547  172.56.213.80:53
3 2013-07-18 04:54:15.821000  192.81.130.82:37192  172.81.123.70:53
4 2013-07-18 04:54:15.811000  172.12.332.11:42547  172.56.213.80:53
```

Then we should fix the IP addresses and remove ports:

```
>>> df[4] = df[4].str.split(':').str.get(0)
>>> df[6] = df[6].str.split(':').str.get(0)
>>> print df.to_string()
                         0_1              4              6
0 2013-07-18 04:54:15.871000  172.12.332.11  172.56.213.80
1 2013-07-18 04:54:15.841000  192.81.130.82  172.81.123.70
2 2013-07-18 04:54:15.831000  172.12.332.11  172.56.213.80
3 2013-07-18 04:54:15.821000  192.81.130.82  172.81.123.70
4 2013-07-18 04:54:15.811000  172.12.332.11  172.56.213.80
```

Lets say you are interested for the source address `172.12.332.11` and destination `172.56.213.80`. We will filter out just those:

```
>>> filtered = df[(df[4] == '172.12.332.11') & (df[6] == '172.56.213.80')]
>>> print filtered.to_string()
                         0_1              4              6
0 2013-07-18 04:54:15.871000  172.12.332.11  172.56.213.80
2 2013-07-18 04:54:15.831000  172.12.332.11  172.56.213.80
4 2013-07-18 04:54:15.811000  172.12.332.11  172.56.213.80
```

Now we need to calculate the difference between the timestamps:

```
>>> timestamps = filtered['0_1']
>>> diffs = (timestamps.shift() - timestamps).dropna()
>>> print diffs.to_string()
2   00:00:00.040000
4   00:00:00.020000
```

And we can now calculate whatever statistics we want:

```
>>> diffs.mean() # this is in nanoseconds
30000000.0
>>> diffs.std()
14142135.62373095
```

***Edit:** For the data you sent me*

```
import io
import pandas as pd

def load_dataframe(filename):
    # First you read the data as a regular csv file and extract the _raw column values
    values = pd.read_csv(filename)['_raw'].values
    # Cleanup the values: remove newline character
    values = map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ' '), values)
    # Add them to a stream
    s = io.StringIO(u'\n'.join(values))
    # And now everithing is the same just read it from the stream
    df = pd.read_table(s, sep='\s+', header=None, parse_dates=[[0,1]])[['0_1',4, 6]]
    df[4] = df[4].str.split(':').str.get(0)
    df[6] = df[6].str.split(':').str.get(0)
    return df

def get_diffs(df, source, destination):
    timestamps = df[(df[4] == source) & (df[6] == destination)]['0_1']
    return (timestamps.shift() - timestamps).dropna()


def main():
    filename = raw_input('Enter filename: ')
    df = load_dataframe(filename)
    while True:
       source = raw_input('Enter source IP: ').strip()
       destination = raw_input('Enter destination IP: ').strip()
       diffs = get_diffs(df, source, destination)
       for i, row in enumerate(diffs):
           print('row %d - row %d = %s' % (i+2, i+1, row.astype('timedelta64[ms]')))
       print('Mean: %s' % diffs.mean())
       yn = raw_input('Again? [y/n]: ').lower().strip()
       if yn != 'y':
            return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example usage:

```
$ python test.py
Enter filename: Data.csv
Enter source IP: 172.16.122.21
Enter destination IP: 172.55.102.107
Mean: 3333333.33333
Std: 5773502.6919
Again? [y/n]: n
```

Comment: Hi victor thanks for your suggestion, however using your method I am getting errors that I have pasted. File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    df = pd.read_table('data.csv', sep=' ', header=None, parse_dates=[[0,1]])[['0_1', 4, 6]]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 141, in read_table
    verbose=verbose, delimiter=delimiter, encoding=None)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 127, in read_csv
    return parser.get_chunk()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 463, in get_chunk

Comment: Can you attach the file you are trying to parse? I constructed the example from the small chunk you wrote in your question, but that's obviously not enough to give me a complete idea what this should actually parse.

Comment: I received the file, is this how your data looks like? Because the first 6 lines are basically junk, after that the data gets kinda regular but not very csv-ish... It's usable, but i don't even know how to interpret the first 6 lines.

Comment: yes this is what the data looks like. so I all i want to do is have a user enter source ip and destination ip. Then match ips based on user input in the csv and calculate the duration of net flows per session followed by the average. So line 2,4,6,8,10 are the same in the example. I want the time difference from line 2-4 to 6 to 8 to 10 will be printed and then the average of all this to be printed as well. Same applies for odd number lines. The goal is user can enter any source and destination ips and the script will check if it matches and if so the calcuation begins.

Comment: So only the things that matche to something like `2013-07-18 04:54:15.871 UDP 172.16.22.187:61452 172.16.22.187:61452 -> 192.168.0.1:53`, that is `DATE TIME PROTOCOL IP:PORT IP:PORT -> IP:PORT` are of interest, everything else is just junk?

Comment: all we actually need is _raw column that has the time, source and destination ip. everything else is not necessary.

Comment: Sorry, but the file you sent me is not a valid csv file. Lines 2-6 are just gibberish. I can either parse the thing I said in the previous comment or I can skip lines 2-7 and post that as a solution. So if one of those things suit you tell me and I'll write them down, if neither of them is good for you then I don't know how to do it, because this file is completely irregular.

Comment: are you viewing this in microsoft excel? if you have that it would be easier to see. Because when I working with this in linux it wassn't the same.

Comment: Oh i got it. It needs manual work, I'll post how to get the data frame in the answer.

Comment: I got an error again Viktor:  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    df = pd.read_table(s, sep='\s+', header=None, parse_dates=[[0,1]])[['0_1',4, 6]]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1374, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1392, in _getitem_array
    raise KeyError("No column(s) named: %s" % str(key[mask]))
KeyError: 'No column(s) named: [0_1 4 6]'

Comment: Which version pandas are you using?

Comment: Change the line `11` to just `df = pd.read_table(s, sep='\s+', header=None, parse_dates=[[0,1]])` and after that put a `print(df.columns)` (delete the rest from the file) and tell me what did it printed out?

Comment: This is what I got based on your comment. array([X.1, X.2, X.3, X.4, X.5, X.6, X.7, X.8, X.9, X.10, X.11, X.12, X.13,
       X.14, X.15, X.16, X.17, X.18, X.19, X.20, X.21, X.22, X.23, X.24,
       X.25, X.26, X.27, X.28, X.29, X.30, X.31, X.32, X.33, X.34, X.35,
       X.36, X.37, X.38, X.39, X.40, X.41, X.42, X.43, X.44, X.45, X.46,
       X.47, X.48, X.49, X.50, X.51, X.52, X.53, X.54, X.55, X.56, X.57], dtype=object)

Comment: Are you using the same file you sent me? And which pandas version do you use? Because this works perfectly on my machine and I get nothing like this.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.3 with pandas .0.7.0 another thing I notice the ip's are entered in the script. What I would like is in linux to do is for user to enter:  python (myscript.py) source Ip Destianation ip fileName.csv  for the script to do the calculations and print all line match time interval and average in the terminal.

Comment: Huh that's the problem, update to a newer version of pandas 0.12. 0.7 is a couple of years old :-/

Comment: Ok nice it did work. however this is not exactly what I wanted. what I am looking for is example below
harry@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ python ip_script.py 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 data.csv

Found 4 matches for [source: 10.0.0.1] and [destination: 10.0.0.2]:

Time between adjacent connections:

Line 2 and Line 3: 0:00:01
Line 3 and Line 4: 0:00:02
Line 4 and Line 5: 0:00:03

Average: 2.0 seconds

Comment: I don't have those IP addresses in the file you sent me, so I cannot check the correctness. I just implemented what you explained.

Comment: Yes this is true,however is there a way we can work with pandas that lets me enter any ip's. I would just like to enter source ip and destination ip and have it do the calcuations.and then print all this out in python. Just as the example you see in my comment above and from my code at the very top. I do not want to have to open python file and change ip's inside the script all the time. Instead tell the script two ip to match against the csv file and then if it matches, do all the calculations and print them out.

Comment: awesome this works great. I really appreciate your help. One last thing and this would be perfect. instead of Std. can we have it print each line and show the difference of it. For examle say. row 2 - row 3 = .2220 row 3-4 = .345 and so forth and then print the mean at the end.

Comment: this is almost complete. Just I would like it to do the calculation matching the same ips. Example in the data.csv row 2 source ip = 172.16.122.21 destination ip =  172.55.102.107 time minus the next line (which is in this csv file is row 4 that match's the same ips of 172.16.122.21  and 172.55.102.107 and print. Then continue with subtraction for the next ip's that match until there are no more and now give me the average.

Comment: I'm really sorry but this is not a "get yourself a free programmer" website. I've already not just answered this question :), but a multiple of following ones... and programmed for you an almost complete application. :) I think it's time for you to start trying something on your own... ;)

Comment: I understand thanks, it was just that I'm new to python and I just started. it's my first programming language didn't understand pandas. besides I'm going to take it future with more functions that I did not include in this. Thanks though for your guidance. :)

Comment: Install IPython (it a wonderful tool for exploring your data) and just start trying things out in the QtConsole or the web notebook. Thats the fastest way to learn. Also there's a bunch of really useful video tutorials on http://pyvideo.org/. Hope that helps :)

Comment: I appreciate your info, I didn't know where to learn csv data manipulation exactly. I currently was just learning from http://learnpythonthehardway.org/